# SQL Server 2012 - Consecutive full backups on heaps

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups

I am not an expert and need your help solving a conundrum.

I have "Database_A" that has 60 tables and the client has requested Full and Differential backups on 15 out of the 60 tables.

Since Differential backups cannot be performed on a subset of the database - I have created a new database - "Database_B" that will hold records from the 15 tables.

This question is only related to the full backups. So during the full backup process - for each table I perform - 
1. DROP TABLE from Database_B
2. Perform SELECT INTO from Database_A to Database_B

Once done, I perform the full backup - 
BACKUP DATABASE [Database_B] TO DISK = '[FilePath]' WITH INIT

When I run the backup I get the following message - 
Processed **1370184** pages for database 'Database_B', file 'Database_B' on file 1.
Processed 2528 pages for database 'Database_B', file 'Database_B_log' on file 1.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed **1372712** pages in 64.028 seconds (167.494 MB/sec).

When I run a consecutive full backup, I get the following message - 
Processed **686752** pages for database 'Database_B', file 'Database_B' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'Database_B', file 'Database_B_log' on file 1.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed **686754** pages in 30.192 seconds (177.704 MB/sec).

Question - Why did the pagecount go down from **1370184** to **686752**? The backup file size also reduces drastically.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have auto-shrink on or are you shrinking? That's the only reason files become smaller.

Comment: No auto-shrink and not shrinking it manually.. The only thing I can think of is the DROP and SELECT INTO almost double the number of pages processed.. You thoughts?

Comment: Figured it out... Added a CHECKPOINT to make sure the transactions (DROP and SELECT INTO per table) were closed.Also might be that dirty pages needed to be flushed.

Comment: This would not explain files becoming smaller. Your question was about that, right? Update: I see, I assumed the files were changing size but it's only the allocated page count! Mystery solved.